# Angular JS: sending form field data in a PUT request (like POST does)

Tags: rest, angularjs

I'm trying to write a client that does all four REST verbs (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) and have gotten all but the PUT done.  The REST/CRUD API I'm working from wants to update an entry by calling PUT /realmen/ID-string and including the key-value pairs as JSON.  For a POST this seems to work "automatically", but not for a PUT.

My HTML looks like:

```
<div id="list">
<form novalidate class="edit-form">
<p>Title <input ng-model="realmen.title" type="text" value="{{realmen.title}}" /></p>
<p>Real Men <input ng-model="realmen.realmen" type="text" value="{{realmen.realmen}}" />  </p>
<p>Real Role-Players <input ng-model="realmen.realroleplayers" type="text" value="realmen.realroleplayers}}" /></p>
<p>Loonies <input ng-model="realmen.loonies" type="text" value="{{realmen.loonies}}" /></p>
<p>Munchkins <input ng-model="realmen.munchkins" type="text" value="{{realmen.munchkins}}" /></p>
<input ng-model="realmen.entryId" type="hidden" value="{{entryId}}"/>
<button ng-click="change()">UPDATE ({{entryId}})"</button></p>
</form>
</div>
```

My controller looks like:

```
$scope.realmen = RealMen.get({entryId: $routeParams.entryId}, function() {
      $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.realmen); // For resetting the form
});

$scope.change = function() {
    console.log($scope.realmen);
    RealMen.update({entryId: $scope.entryId}, function() {
            $location.path('/');
    });
}
```

And finally, my services look like:

```
angular.module('realmenServices', ['ngResource']).
factory('RealMen', function($resource){
    var RealMen = $resource(
        'http://localhost\\:3000/realmen/:entryId',
        {},
        {
                query: {method:'GET', params:{entryId:''}, isArray:true},
                post: {method:'POST'},
                update: {method: 'PUT', params:{entryId:'@entryId'}},
                remove: {method:'DELETE'}
        });

    return RealMen;
});
```

The PUT is getting called with the correct id value in the URL, but the Request Payload only contains the entryId, so the backend API gets no expected keys and values and essentially blanks out the record in the database.

The console.log($scope.realmen) does show the form fields, along with a lot of extra data. I  tried calling RealMen.update($scope.realmen, ...) (similarly to calling .save()), but all those extra fields are tacked on as query string parameters to the URL in a spectacularly ugly fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `$scope.realmen` is a resource instance, instead of using `RealMen.update`, you can just call `$scope.realmen.$update()` (note that there is a "$"). The instance action method will take care of sending the data for you.

Comment: Thanks again, jaux.  The $update is calling the PUT URL with the correct format (/realmen/ID-string), but the payload has two extra fields (_id and entryID) and are causing an error from MongoDB:

Error updating entry: MongoError: cannot change _id of a document old:{ _id: ObjectId('51ce617853c6f60000000001'), entryId: "51ce617853c6f60000000001" } new:{ _id: "51ce617853c6f60000000001", entryId: "51ce617853c6f60000000001", title: "A", realmen: "B", realroleplayers: "C", loonies: "D", munchkins: "E" }

Is there a way to strip these out of the request payload?